# How for loop subscript which return blank item

Tags: bash

```
for i in 'a b' 'c d'; do echo $i;done
```

This can print two lines:

> a b
>
> c d

```
for i in $(echo "'a b' 'c d'");do echo $i;done
```

This will print four lines:

```
'a
b'
'c
d'
```

I try to use array with `eval`.This works

```
eval array=($(echo "'a b' 'c d'")
for ((i=0;i<${#array[@]};i++));do echo ${array[$i]};done
```

This work well and print two line:

> a b
>
> c d

Is there another easy way to do this?

I wish iterate for i in $(echo "'a b' 'c d'") like for i in 'a b' 'c d'

Comment: What are you *trying* to do, i.e., what is in the input and what should the output be? Messing with `eval` and various nested quoting usually is the wrong approach.

Comment: @Rubens No,if don't use eval.array will have four items.you can try,this happens because of bash parse strategy

Comment: @chepner I have update question,you can see the output now.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with `for i in 'a b' 'c d'`? Also, the example is obviously artificial, so it's to tell why you feel the need to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have some variable that was constructed as a space separated list, and that your items may contain white spaces.

This, as you can see, is awkward to iterate over in bash.

If you have any control over the variable generation consider make it like this:

```
lines="a b
c d"
( IFS=$'\n' ; for i in $lines ; do echo $i ; done ; )
```

If you don't have control over the variable creation you can still make it a bit less    convoluted:

```
eval array=($(echo "'a b' 'c d'"))
for i in "${array[@]}" ; do echo $i ; done
```

---

**Update** -- As commented below, some explanations are in order:

*1st solution:*

- From man bash:

  > IFS
  > The Internal Field Separator that is used for word splitting after expansion and to split lines into words with the read builtin command. The default value is ``<space><tab><newline>''.
- Also note the somewhat convoluted way of assigning <newline> to IFS: `IFS=$'\n'`
- Here we use `(` ... `)` to encapsulate the scope of IFS within a sub-shell. You can do without it if you don't care that the value of IFS will be changed, or if you devise an other way to restore it's original value, e.g. `saved_ifs=$IFS ; ... ; IFS=$saved_ifs`

*2nd solution:*

- We use `eval array=($(echo "'a b' 'c d'"))` and not `array=('a b' 'c d')`, because when we have `myvar="'a b' 'c d'"` (or any other combination I tried) `array=($myvar)` will not do the right thing (with or without quotes), but `eval array=($(echo $myvar))` will be evaluated to `array=('a b' 'c d')`.
- Note the difference between `"${array[@]}"` and `"${array[*]}"`; it is similar to the difference between "$@" and "$*" (again from man bash):

  > * Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one.  When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the  IFS  special  variable.   That is, "$*" is equivalent to "$1c$2c...", where c is the first character of the value of the IFS variable.  If IFS is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces.  If IFS is null, the parameters are joined without intervening separators.
  >
  > @ Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one.  When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word.  That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ... If the double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last part of the original word. When there are no positional parameters, "$@" and $@ expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).

Comment: cool.but I don't understand the first code.What's IFS meaning?Would you please explain?3x

Comment: I have google advanced bash-script.Seems IFS is the best choice,3q

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you think you need `eval` here. The following will do the same thing:

```
array=('a b' 'c d')
for line in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: Sorry,you don't understand my situation.Please see @Chen Levy's answer.

Comment: I don't, because you haven't explained it yet. If you are actually hard-coding an array value with `eval array=($(echo "'a b' 'c d'")`, don't: `array=('a b' 'c d')` is much clearer. If that's simply an example to produce an array whose elements contain whitespace, then  my solution works fine. Or is your real question how to work with a single string of the form produced by your `echo`, which you receive as the output of an external program?